# Equivalent of Nashorn's importPackage in graal.js script engine

Tags: java, graalvm, graaljs

I am migrating old code from JDK 8 to JDK 12.

In the process, I have noticed `importPackage` does not exist when using the `"graal.js"` script engine. It exists when using `"javascript"` for the script engine.

Is there any way to achieve the same functionality with `"graal.js"`? The Nashorn migration doc on the GraalJS repository does not cover this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`importPackage` is originally from Rhino. Even Nashorn supports it when Rhino/Mozilla compatibility is requested explicitly using `load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");` only, see [Rhino Migration Guide](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Rhino+Migration+Guide) in the documentation of Nashorn.

Graal.js has Nashorn compatibility mode and it supports `load("nashorn:mozilla_compat.js");` in this mode.

So, you can use something like

```
System.setProperty("polyglot.js.nashorn-compat", "true");
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("graal.js");
System.out.println(engine.eval("load('nashorn:mozilla_compat.js'); importPackage('java.awt'); new Point();"));
```

(it prints `java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]` which shows that the package `java.awt` was imported successfully).